# Is there an adjective for "of eight years, eight years old"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, numbers

I was looking for "of eight years", and I saw "octoni, ae, a."
Then I saw:
Septuennis "of seven years, seven years old. (Puer Septuennis, a seven years old boy)
Quinquennis: "of five years, five years old
(Puer quinquennis, a five years old boy)
Could I say "puer octonnis", or should I use the genitive "Puer octonorum annorum"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to supplement Sebastian's answer, *octoni* is the distributive adjective for *octo* and it means "eight times" or "eight at a time." It is not the same type of word as *septuennis*. For that, Sebastian is correct, and you want *octennis*.

However, you *can* use *octonus* for age, and it can be used as a mere substitute for *octo*. Just take Ovid's *Metamorphoses* (5.50) as an example:

> bis adhuc octonis integer annis
> Now untouched at sixteen (twice eight-times) years old

And it's not limited to poetry, as Pliny the Elder often uses it in his *Historia Naturalis* as well (e.g. 8.201, 10.107).

> columbae et turtures octonis annis vivunt.
> Pigeons and turtle-doves live for eight years. (Pliny, NH 10.107)

That said, you'll still need a noun to go with it.

Answer (score 10):

The word is [*octennis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Doctennis). You can say *puer octennis* – but it's an extremely unusual word and not classical.

More common ways to express the idea are:

- *puer octo annos natus* – an eight year old boy
- *puer octo annorum* – a boy of eight years
- *puer nonum annum agens* – a boy living in his ninth year

Comment: Thanks,  Sebastian. I don't care about the word being classical. Actually,  I don't even like classical Latin.